# how to get to know programmatically whether any TTS engine installed in my device or not?

Tags: android

I would like to know programmatically how to get TTS engine info of the device for e.g. whether any TTS engine is installed or not , if installed then what are those and what are the different languages supported by each TTS engine?
I have to use Android version 2.1(api level 7) to achieve this.

Please help me to implement this feature.

Regards,

Piks

Answer (score 14):

You can check it by first sending an intent for result

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then you can check it that if you have installed TTS engine or not in onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(requestCode == 0){
    if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
    installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    startActivity(installIntent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Installed Now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: but how this code helps me to know that whether a particular language supported by the TTS engine or not and 2nd thing : how to set the default engine to other TTS engine?

Comment: Answer 1st: Theres a function called isLanguageAvailable(Locale.FRANCE); Answer 2nd: I didn't understand your question! @piks

Comment: second question is: suppose device is having more than one TTS engine installed and one engine set it to default(generally PICO) but default TTS doesn't support all languages lets say Portuguese , in this scenario My app should check first whether currently set default engine supports Portuguese or not if not then it will set other installed TTS and verify the same..how to achieve it programmaticaly?

Comment: int result = TTS.setLanguage(new Locale("pt"); <- Here you go :) Hope it helps @piks

Comment: by this way, If there is no TTS engine on the mobile, the program will not run!
Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 7):

This gives you the list of TTS Engines installed on your Android.

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
for (TextToSpeech.EngineInfo engines : tts.getEngines()) {
Log.d("Engine Info " , engines.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To save your clicks:

Launch this to check if TTS is installed or not:

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

and then get result in this:

```
private TextToSpeech mTts;
protected void onActivityResult(
    int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
        // success, create the TTS instance
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    } else {
        // missing data, install it
        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent.setAction(
            TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: but how this code helps me to know that whether a particular language supported by the TTS engine or not and 2nd thing : how to set the default engine to other TTS engine?

Comment: With this solution, If the TTS engine is disabled, the app will not run!
Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This official [Android Blog Post](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html) gives you the best practice to detect if the TTS Engine is installed and ready to use, as well as other practices on TTS.

Answer (score 0):

To check for installed TTS engines, you need to first initialize the TTS engine. Then use the returned TTS engine object to call the function `getEngines()` to know if any TTS engine is initialized or not.

Cool, enough talk, here's the code that works:-

```kotlin
    fun initializeEngine(context: Context) {
        tts = TextToSpeech(context){ initStatus ->
            if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
             // TTS engine initialized successfully
            }
        }
    }

   fun supportedEnginesList(): List<TextToSpeech.EngineInfo>?{
      return tts?.engines?
   }
```