# What is right way to use TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA in 2.1 for non default language?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(requestCode == 0){
if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Intent installIntent = new Intent();
installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
startActivity(installIntent);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Installed Now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
```

Guys,
Above code works only if **OS Default language == TTS installed language**.
If they are different, it branches to **ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA**.
Obviously, it should be additional data for **TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA** to specify which language data need to be checked but I cannot find it.

Following scenario come to play when user run something like a French – German dictionary on with English as default OS language.

Scenario:
SVOX + German, French languages are installed.
Default language set to English or something other language.
The key it’s not German or French
It looks like **TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA** check for English language presence in SVOX and come back with **CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL**.
If language set to German the result will be **CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS**

There are similar questions, but it looks like people trying to answer doesn’t understand question completely.
[how to get to know programmatically whether any TTS engine installed in my device or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911530/how-to-get-to-know-programmatically-whether-any-tts-engine-installed-in-my-devic)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting getting the extra `TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR`

According to the source code in [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/example/android/ttsengine/CheckVoiceData.java), it will enable you to pass the parameter of the voice locale that you'd specifically like to check.